# two views with match_parent in linear_layout in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Is it possible to have two views that are the same height of the activity screen inside of a linear_layout inside of a scrollview? I tried achieving this like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>   
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The only thing that appears one button with the height of the screen. The other button seems to have disappeared.

I suppose it is paradoxical to have two views to with the attribute match_parent.

However, I was hoping to get two views the same size of the available screen using xml, and having the scrollview make both views accessible. I am aware that it can be done via java, but I want an answer for xml.

Comment: use weights - [weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) and layout_weight , it wont really give you what you want , but you can probably achieve some what of the expected behaviour

Comment: Right, as far as I know, using weights won't get the buttons to be the same size of the available screen, the available screen will be apportioned to the buttons. I'm really looking to see if I can get the buttons the same size as the available screen and for scrolling to work.

Comment: @ginsengtang Accept my answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: I was already aware of this answer for java, as I have clearly said in my question. I want an answer in xml or at the very least reasons why there is no way to achieve this in xml.

Answer (score 0):

In `Linear Layout` you have to define two things...

1 .`android:orientation="vertical"`

2 .`android:weightSum="2"`
weightSum is sum of all element in it's parent layout.It Enable you to define the proportion of width/height a element should take in a layout..

> For further details go to [**weightSum**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="but 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="but 1" />
  </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

output

[image]

Comment: using weights will not get the buttons to be the same size as the available screen

Comment: I don't think you understood. Using weights will not make each button the same height as the available screen. Right now, each button is half the size of the available screen.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this in XML only.

As android support multiple screen sizes, At runtime you need to check for each device , the height for each device can be calculated like this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int height = size.y;
```

With above code you will get the height of screen and you need to set this height in dp to your view at runtime.

Do this in your activity for both the buttons:

```
        // get view you want to resize
        Button but1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1); 


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams listLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    height , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        but1.setLayoutParams(listLayoutParams);
```

Comment: The constructor of LayoutParams is LayoutParams(width, height). The other way round you wrote.